# Custom sort list based on another

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm trying to sort a list of files based on a desired extension preference. Let's say I have a list that looks like:

```yaml
- name: Declare all assets
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    asset_list:
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz.sbom
      - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
      - artifact.deb
      - artifact.appimage
      - artifact_amd64
      - artifact_amd64.sha256sum
```

Now, I'd like to get sort them in some order which could be changed by prompt, say: `['deb', 'appimage', 'tar.gz', '']`. In this case `''` means no extension, which in this case means it's a linux executable. Regarding the files that don't match the extension, I'm not intereseted in them, I'd prefer them to be removed.

Is this possible to do without writing a custom filter? I had the idea to prepend the extensions to the items with something like: `map('regex_replace', '^(.*\\.)(deb|appimage|tar\\.gz)$', '\\2 \\1\\2')` but I would still need to prepend a number or something to pass it through the regular ansible sort before trying to remove it to get the final filename. The entire thing looks very complicated and hard to read in that case and I don't have a good solution for no extension.

Comment: May we know what do you plan to do with the results later? Also, I'm a bit confused by "sort them in some order which could be changed by prompt" - does it mean that you want the resulting list to only have the items matching the extensions you define, and they should go in the order you define?

Comment: "_Is this possible to do without writing a custom filter?_", maybe, but the recommendation and probably much simpler would be a Custom Filter.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev The goal is to install the best candidate, after applying a buch of filters to it, like OS, architecture and things of the sort, but as you could tell, deb does not work for all OSes, and sometimes even two possible files can work, in which case I would need to know if there's a candidate based on all filters. For example there may be a deb file but it's only for x64, and my system is arm64, in which case I would have to look for the next best file.

Comment: @RevanDarth You should have started from this. [`package`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html) module should do it for you automatically.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev package is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking at github releases for the filenames, and a lot of the packages I'm looking for are not packaged by the OS package manager, or, in case they do, don't have the version that I'm looking for. I need to test with specific versions of these artifacts.

Comment: @RevanDarth then you might want to look into [`quera.github.install_from_github`](https://github.com/QueraTeam/ansible-github) module that can pass the package type based on the discovered OS/arch facts via `asset_regex ` (see the link on facts gathering in my answer for details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lists of the files and the extensions

```yaml
    asset_list:
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz.sbom
      - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
      - artifact.deb
      - artifact.appimage
      - artifact_amd64
      - artifact_amd64.sha256sum
    asset_order: [deb, appimage, tar.gz]
```

Reverse the items

```yaml
    asset_list_reverse: "{{ asset_list | map('reverse') }}"
    asset_order_reverse: "{{ asset_order | map('reverse') }}"
```

Use the fact that the test [match](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings):

> succeeds if it finds the pattern at the beginning of the string

and create the ordered list of files with extensions

```yaml
  asset_list_order: |
    {% filter flatten %}
    [{% for ext in asset_order_reverse %}
    {{ asset_list_reverse | select('match', ext) | map('reverse') }},
    {% endfor %}]
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  asset_list_order:
  - artifact.deb
  - artifact.appimage
  - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
  - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
```

Create a list of executables

```yaml
  asset_list_exe: "{{ asset_list | reject('search', '\\.') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  asset_list_exe:
  - artifact_amd64
```

Add the lists

```yaml
  result: "{{ asset_list_order + asset_list_exe }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - artifact.deb
  - artifact.appimage
  - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
  - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
  - artifact_amd64
```

---

**Notes**

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    asset_list:
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz.sbom
      - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
      - artifact.deb
      - artifact.appimage
      - artifact_amd64
      - artifact_amd64.sha256sum
    asset_list_reverse: "{{ asset_list | map('reverse') }}"

    asset_order: [deb, appimage, tar.gz]
    asset_order_reverse: "{{ asset_order | map('reverse') }}"

    asset_list_order: |
      {% filter flatten %}
      [{% for ext in asset_order_reverse %}
      {{ asset_list_reverse | select('match', ext) | map('reverse') }},
      {% endfor %}]
      {% endfilter %}
    asset_list_exe: "{{ asset_list | reject('search', '\\.') }}"
    result: "{{ asset_list_order + asset_list_exe }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: asset_list_order
    - debug:
        var: asset_list_exe
    - debug:
        var: result
```

---

2. If you want to put the empty string into the list, for example,

```yaml
  asset_order: [deb, appimage, tar.gz, '']
```

remove it from the list of the reversed extensions

```yaml
  asset_order_reverse: "{{ asset_order | select | map('reverse') }}"
```

and test it when assembling the result

```yaml
  result: "{{ ('' in asset_order) |
              ternary(asset_list_order + asset_list_exe,
                      asset_list_order) }}"
```

---

3. The next option is to create the complete list in Jinja. This keeps the order of the extensions including the executables. The example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    asset_list:
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz.sbom
      - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
      - artifact.deb
      - artifact.appimage
      - artifact_amd64
      - artifact_amd64.sha256sum
    asset_order: [deb, '', appimage, tar.gz]

    asset_list_reverse: "{{ asset_list | map('reverse') }}"
    asset_order_reverse: "{{ asset_order | map('reverse') }}"

    result: |
      [{% for ext in asset_order_reverse %}
      {% if ext|length > 0 %}
      {{ asset_list_reverse | select('match', ext) | map('reverse') }},
      {% else %}
      {{ asset_list | reject('search', '\.') }},
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result | flatten
```

gives

```yaml
  result | flatten:
  - artifact.deb
  - artifact_amd64
  - artifact.appimage
  - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
  - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
```

Comment: I'm simply amazed. Very beautiful solution in it's simplicity. I had no idea one could use fors in varables like this.

That being said I have an error if I also add the flatten filter to asset_list_order, the error reads: "expected str instance, list found", but if I apply the flatten filter in another variable it works as expected.

The only thing that I would say can't be easily done with this solution is putting the executable, no extension, in the middle of the order of extensions. I'm guessing I could slice the list, before and after, add the executables, then flatten it. Still, thx!

Comment: This solution does not work with an empty extension like in the original @RevanDarth's example - some of the items get randomly duplicated. For example, for `asset_order: [appimage, deb, '', tar.gz]` I get `"result": ["artifact.appimage",
"artifact.deb",
"artifact_amd64.tar.gz",
"artifact_amd64.tar.gz.sbom",
"artifact_arm64.tar.gz",
"artifact.deb",
"artifact.appimage",
"artifact_amd64",
"artifact_amd64.sha256sum",
"artifact_amd64.tar.gz",
"artifact_arm64.tar.gz",
"artifact_amd64"]`

Comment: The addition of an empty string is simple: 1) Select nonempty strings in the list of the reversed extensions and 2) test empty string when assembling the result. See the 2nd note.

Comment: I added one more example of how to keep the order. See the 3rd note.

Answer (score 2):

I have three answers for your question (scroll down to the real problem).

#### Answer to the original question

Basically, the idea could be the following:

- detect the available extensions
- create a mapping "full artifact name - extension" for simpler processing (otherwise, we would need to have a more complex loop)
- extract the artifacts that match the prompt list in a loop to keep the order.

An example playbook will look like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Filter the assets based on the given list of extensions
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    sort_prompt: ['deb', 'appimage', 'tar.gz', '']
    asset_list:
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz.sbom
      - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
      - artifact.deb
      - artifact.appimage
      - artifact_amd64
      - artifact_amd64.sha256sum
    asset_list_extensions: >
      {{ asset_list | map('split', '.', 1) | map(attribute='1', default='') }}
    asset_list_zipped: >
      {{ asset_list | zip(asset_list_extensions) }}
    asset_list_filtered: []
  tasks:
    - name: Filter the assets
      set_fact:
        asset_list_filtered: >
          {{ 
            asset_list_filtered 
              + asset_list_zipped | selectattr(1, 'equalto', item) 
          }}
      loop: "{{ sort_prompt }}"

    - name: Display the results
      vars:
        asset_list_filtered: "{{ asset_list_filtered | map(attribute='0') }}"
      debug:
        var: asset_list_filtered
```

This would give the following results:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  asset_list_filtered:
  - artifact.deb
  - artifact.appimage
  - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
  - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
  - artifact_amd64
```

Some bits of explanation:

```yaml
    # We will extract the available extensions:
    #   map('split', '.', 1) prepares a list of two items:
    #     - package name
    #     - package extension (e.g. all the remaining substring)
    #   map(attribute='1', default='') extracts the extension:
    #     attribute='1' is the same as some_list[1]
    #     default='' will cover a missing extension
    asset_list_extensions: >
      {{ asset_list | map('split', '.', 1) | map(attribute='1', default='') }}
```

```yaml
    # Here we're merging the lists of artifact names and the extensions
    # to have a link between them
    asset_list_zipped: >
      {{ asset_list | zip(asset_list_extensions) }}
```

```yaml
    # We will start to build the resulting list from here.
    # Could be replaced by `| default([]) in the template itself`
    asset_list_filtered: []
```

#### Solution for a case when the package name contains dots

In fact, that's even simpler than the original. But instead of filters, we will rely on regular expressions and Jinja2 templating:

```yaml
- name: Filter the assets based on the given list of extensions
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    sort_prompt: [ deb, appimage, '', tar.xz, tar.gz ]
    asset_list:
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
      - artifact_amd64.tar.gz.sbom
      - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
      - artifact.deb
      - artifact.appimage
      - artifact_amd64
      - artifact_amd64.sha256sum
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64-musl
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64-musl.tar.xz
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64.tar.gz
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64.tar.xz
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-armv6
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-armv6-musl
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-armv6-musl.tar.gz
      - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-armv6-musl.tar.xz
    asset_list_filtered: []
  tasks:
    - name: Filter the assets
      vars:
        package: mise
        regex_to_find_non_empty_extensions: '^{{ package }}.*({{ item }})$'
        regex_to_find_empty_extensions: '^{{ package }}$'
      set_fact:
        asset_list_filtered: >
          {{ 
            asset_list_filtered +
              asset_list 
              | map('regex_search', regex_to_find_non_empty_extensions) 
              | select            
              if item != ''
              else
                asset_list 
                | map('regex_search', regex_to_find_empty_extensions) 
                | select
          }}
      loop: "{{ sort_prompt }}"

    - name: List the results
      debug:
        var: asset_list_filtered
```

Now we will use the `package` variable to filter out the results:

- For package `artifact`:

  ```
  ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e package=artifact
  ```

  ```yaml
  asset_list_filtered:
  - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
  - artifact_arm64.tar.gz
  ```
- For package `artifact_amd64` (note that at this point making the solution clever enough to distinct `_` and `-` would be equal to reinventing an existing module):

  ```
  ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e package=artifact_amd64
  ```

  ```yaml
  asset_list_filtered:
  - artifact_amd64
  - artifact_amd64.tar.gz
  ```
- For package `mise`:

  ```
  ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e package=mise
  ```

  Or even `mise-v2024.3.1`:

  ```
  ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e package=mise-v2024.3.1
  ```

  ```yaml
  asset_list_filtered:
  - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64-musl.tar.xz
  - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64.tar.xz
  - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-armv6-musl.tar.xz
  - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz
  - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-arm64.tar.gz
  - mise-v2024.3.1-linux-armv6-musl.tar.gz
  ```

#### Solution for the real problem behind the question

For your particular case, chances are that you don't need to implement this logic:

- Ansible has a built-in [`package`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html) module that is agnostic to the OS distribution and selects the package automatically;
- Ansible can gather the facts about the hosts that it is running on, including the OS and distribution name. Generally, one should rely on them instead of selecting the package extension manually. Check out [Conditionals based on ansible_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) for details.
- If you're installing the releases from GitHub, you might want to look into [`quera.github.install_from_github`](https://github.com/QueraTeam/ansible-github) module that can select the package type based on the discovered OS/arch facts passed via `asset_regex`.

Comment: Thank you. This is an excelent solution, and it is quite a lot simpler than the other one posted here if the no extension case is also condiered. From that perspective it does solve my original question, however the biggest downside is that if there are assets that have a period in them before the extension, like, for example [this](https://github.com/jdx/mise/releases) project. I admit it was not a consideration in my original question, but the other solution is more flexible with this. I believe that there might be some that prefer your solution but unfortunately it falls a bit short for me.

Comment: Thank you also for posting about the [quera.github.install_from_github](https://github.com/QueraTeam/ansible-github) project. I don't know how you found it but it does indeed look to solve a very similar problem to mine, but it does have one major shortcomming, and that is it only supports assets in github releases and sometimes those assets can be linked in the github description like [helm](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases) does. But still, excelent find!

Comment: @DarthBanana indeed, that was not part of the original question. But it turned out that this would be even simpler. I added this case to my answer. Any further improvement, however, is too close to reimplementing the existing solution. Regarding "how you found it" - I just googled "ansible install github release" :-)